How to rotate and flip a Bitmap to a specific orientation, regardless of its initial position?
I'm facing an issue where I want to ensure the image is positioned exactly like Image No. 1 (F):

However, when selecting an image from the phone gallery, the image might appear in any orientation or position. How can I rotate and flip the image to match the orientation of Image No. 1 (F)?
Also the same issue is happening when I take image from the camera itself , so it's not only specific to exif data
Here's my current code:
private Bitmap getStoredImage() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("app_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String imagePath = sharedPreferences.getString("front_face_image", null);

    if (imagePath != null) {
        File imgFile = new File(imagePath);
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    return null;  // Return null if the image path is not found or the file does not exist
}


The issue you're facing has something to do with the EXIF metadata of the image. You can find some more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740776/get-exif-orientation-tag-rotate-to-proper-orientation-process-image-and-save-th?rq=3

thats not the case, i only mentioned the gallery , but im even taking images from the camera directly , for camera it is roateting the image No :- 6 ,

When you're decoding the raw bitmap from the file, the decoding process skips the EXIF data. Instead, you should generate the Bitmap considering the EXIF metadata, which isn't limited to just camera images. Many JPG files contain embedded EXIF data, so you should at least check if it's an EXIF issue by debugging it properly.

To clarify, the issue didn’t happen when I was loading images using the string path stored in Shared Preferences. However, I was worried that the image might get accidentally deleted from the gallery, so I switched to using a bitmap. This way, the image is saved in a directory that's hidden from the user, preventing accidental deletion.
I'm not using any backend for storing the images. Once an image is uploaded to the app, either from the camera or gallery, it is stored in memory. The image will be replaced when a new one is uploaded, which is an intended feature, not a bug.

This question is similar to: Android get Orientation of a camera Bitmap? And rotate back -90 degrees. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try this,
Use this code to rotate your bitmap in specific orientation. You will get rotated bitmap in result. You need to pass imagePath (path of image to be rotated) and bitmap to this method.
      public int getCameraPhotoOrientation(String imagePath, Bitmap bmp){
            int rotate = 0;
            try {
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
    
                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        rotate = 270;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        rotate = 180;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        rotate = 90;
                        break;
                }
    
    
                Matrix mat = new Matrix();
                mat.postRotate((rotate)); //degree how much you rotate i rotate 270
                Bitmap bMapRotate=Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0,0,bmp.getWidth(),bmp.getHeight(), mat, true);
 File myDir = new File(getContext().getFilesDir() + "/user_image");
            if(!myDir.exists()){
                myDir.mkdirs();
            }

            String fname = "IMG_SEARCH.jpg";
            File file = new File (myDir, fname);
            if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bMapRotate.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Log.i("RotateImage", "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
            Log.i("RotateImage", "Rotate value: " + rotate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return rotate;
    }

